# I want to hide specific cells if rows got specific word inside

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, datagrid, hide

i want to hide specific cells but if there is x word inside the row.

from

[this is mydatagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mU4J.png)

to

[this is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzASA.png)

Comment: I can't find RowDataBound event.

Comment: The logic you intend is not really clear from your question, but the principle for checking and for hiding should be pretty much what @RahulHendawe mentioned. As for where you execute it... that depends on the moment on which you want to _do_ this filtering.

Comment: @RahulHendawe im working with windows forms c#. there isn't rowdatabound event.

Comment: Either save in the Tag and clear the value or code CellPainting to suppress drawing the text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the rows and test the values :

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in myDatagridview.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells["y"].Value == "a")
    {
        row.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

You may want to add `.ToString()` after `row.Cells["y"].Value` if you are comparing string values

Since you just want to hide the value and not the entire row, just replace `row.Visible = false` by `row.Cells["x"].Value = null`

Comment: "y" is not a cell. "y" is column.

Comment: Just replace "x" and "y" with column index. In your exemple x = Cells[1] and y = Cells[2]

Comment: It didn't work :(.

Comment: If you want us to be helpful, at least try to give us some code you tried to execute, and the error you get when you are trying to execute it..

Comment: I'll edit my question, wait please.

Comment: can you help now

Comment: This hides the row not a cell! setting the value to null loses the value.